# Use Paypal as a event ticket system (or is there an alternative)

Tags: paypal, ticket-system

I’m working in a NPO that holds a conference once a year. This is our first year and the conference is in March so we are about ready to open up for a ticket sale.
My problem is that I don’t have any experience with setting up a ticket system. My initially idea was to use Paypal but after being browsing around at Paypal I think that it might not be suitable for such a system. I could be mistaken and just haven’t spent enough time to see all its potential but I’ve tried to look for alternatives.

Because we are an NPO the most favorable alternative is to get it for free, maybe with a sponsor deal but hasn’t found any. Eventbrite has no free offer for NPOs and can’t see if others have it.

My question is twofold:
Can I use Paypal for such a system, which has to deal with the payment but also registration of each person signing up, saving them in a database with a unique registration number and with the possibility to send out an E-ticket.

Or if Paypal isn’t the right way to go, is there any one with knowledge of alternatives that might be interesting in doing it for free for a NPO and maybe to get a sponsor agreement where we will promote them on our website with a logo and into printed material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use EventBrite. Give them a ring and see what they can do for you. It's the best solution and has PayPal payment processing integrated.
PayPal is a payment gateway; not a full-fledged ticketing system, so don't try and make it one in my opinion.

Comment: Thank, I've send them an message asking about their services an prices.  
You are probably right about Paypal, to leave it what it is and not mrore. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Robert's right about paypal being a payment gateway, but I'd recommend EventHoller over EventBrite. It's a similar site but has a couple of better features and it's free event management, as opposed to that annoying $1 + 2% or whatever EventBrite charges per ticket. It also has paypal integrated.